# Prove that this algorithm is correct

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, binary-search, proof-of-correctness

I don't get how this works.
Could you please prove this? Thanks.

```
def binary_search(array) -> int:
    def condition(value) -> bool:
        pass

    left, right = min(search_space), max(search_space) # could be [0, n], [1, n] etc. Depends on problem
    while left < right:
        mid = left + (right - left) // 2
        if condition(mid):
            right = mid
        else:
            left = mid + 1
    return left
```

Comment: Show some effort : What did you get ? Where are you stuck ? [Is this homework?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Please comment your post, what's your goal, not only your not working code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would benefit from reading/watching a video on BinarySearch
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3YID7liBug.